# Ember: change attribute of nullable relationship

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, relationship, belongs-to

I have a model company and a model address. `company.address` belongs to address. So when I fetch a company record  `model(params) {return this.store.findRecord('company', params.companyID);}`I can access the address attributes with `model.address.street`. But when my backend retruns address: null because the company dosnt have a relationship with an address and I want that the user can set the street by a input field, I get the error `Assertion Failed: Cannot delegate set('street', a) to the 'content' property of object proxy <(subclass of Ember.ObjectProxy):ember1458>: its 'content' is undefined."`

Here is the json with the null relationship:

```
{"data": {
    "attributes": {"name": "test-company"}, "id": "5", 
    "relationships": {
        "address": {
            "data": null
            }
        }, 
        "type": "companies"
    }
}
```

So how can I avoid this error? I could proof the model.address after fetching the company record if it has an id but doing this in every route isnt really smart.

Answer (score 0):

Well initially your route model hook should make sure that organization has address with a valid ember-data record. If not, then create an empty one.

```
model: function(params) {
        const store = this.get('store');

        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            org: store.findRecord('orgnanization', params.id).then(org => { 
                 org.get('address').then(address => {
                      if(Ember.isNone(address)) {
                         org.set('address', store.createRecrord('organization.address', {});
                      }
                 })
            }),
        });
 },
```

Now your input can have direct binding to organization.address.street because it is now related to ember-data record at all times.

```
 {{input type="text" value=model.org.address.street}}
```

And when editing  You would first need to save address record, so it will have an id and then save the original organization.

```
 editOrganization: function() {
    const org = this.get('model.org')
    const saveAddressPromise = org.get('address').then(address => {
        return Ember.isPresent(address.get('street')) ? address.save() : EMPTY_PROMISE(null);
    }); // If street is present save the address, other wise send empty promise that resolves to null

   return saveAddressPromise.then(address => {
       if(Ember.isNone(address) {
         org.set('address', null); // The street is not present still. dont save address record
       }

       return org.save();
   }).catch(sendError).finally(doSomething);
}
```

Another way would be to save an empty record everytime, then you would not have this .street check.

Nb! Empty_promise code example

```
return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(value);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think it will work fine to create a new record every time the company.address is empty. But is there a way to do it in every model automatically? I tried it in the application serializer's normalizeResponse() without success. Do you have got an idea for that?